# Is it possible to pass a return value from a function as the return value of the main function in C?

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, return-value

my program (so far) is supposed to check if there is exactly one additional command line argument. If that is not the case, my main function should return 1. For readability reasons, I decided to outsource that checking to another function. The problem is, that I don't know how to make the main function return the same value as the helper function. My code is the following:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    checkNumberOfArguments(argc);
    return 0;
}

int checkNumberOfArguments(int argc)
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Error");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How can I solve that problem in an **elegant** way?

Comment: `return checkNumberOfArguments(argc);` is the normal way. I don't know if this is **elegant**.

Comment: That would work, thank you @MikeCAT. The problem is, that when I would expand the program to do more stuff, the return value of main would be fixed to that specific function's return value. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Like `int ret = checkNumberOfArguments(argc); return ret;`? It seems the only conditions written here is "the main function return the same value as the helper function". What is your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning from the initial call to `main` is defined to be “equivalent to calling the `exit` function with the value returned by the `main` function as its argument” (C 2018 5.1.2.2.3 1). Therefore, to have the same effect as returning from the initial call to `main` with value `x`, all you need to do is call `exit(x)`:

```
#include <stdlib.h> // To declare “exit”.

int checkNumberOfArguments(int argc)
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Error");
        exit(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Save the return value of the function.  If it's nonzero, return it, otherwise continue on.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int rval = checkNumberOfArguments(argc);
    if (rval != 0) {
        return rval;
    }
    ...
    return 0;
}
```